# Subtract values in one list from corresponding values in another list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
A = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
B = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

How do I subtract each value in one list from the corresponding value in the other list and create a list such that:

```
C = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Thanks.

Comment: If this is a one-off, you'd want what @sven-marnach posted. If you're doing some more things with them, you likely want an actual vector class as opposed to lists. Numpy is popular.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a list comprehension

```py
C = [a - b for a, b in zip(A, B)]
```

or `map()`:

```py
from operator import sub
C = map(sub, A, B)
```

Comment: I seem to miss the questions I actually know answers to :), but yes, listcomp and map with operator.sub. I'd go for map or numpy, but yeah... +1

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you. Will look into 'map' , have not come across that yet. But again, thank you.

Comment: @Sven Marnach
Another obvious issue I have encountered while using both map() and the numpy array, is unequal array length. IF A is shorter ,Is it possible to subtract 1 list from another, for the length of the shortest list? something like: 
for i in A:
C = map(sub,A,B)

Comment: @manengstudent: The list-comprehension version stops on the shorter sequence (since `zip()` does).  If you prefer the `map()` version, you could use import the new version of `map()` from `future_builtins` or `imap()` from `itertools`.  These functions return iterators, though, so you need to wrap the result in a call to `list()` if desired.

Comment: @SvenMarnach . Great, worked a treat. Always something to learn :)

Answer (score 15):

Since you appear to be an engineering student, you'll probably want to get familiar with [numpy](https://numpy.org). If you've got it installed, you can do

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([2,4,6,8])
>>> b = np.array([1,3,5,7])
>>> c = a-b
>>> print c
[1 1 1 1]
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I will indeed start looking into it, I have the module installed. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this could be usefull.

```
C = []
for i in range(len(A)):
    difference = A[i] - B[i]
    C.append(difference)
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
A = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
B = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

[A[x]-B[x] for x in range(len(B))]

#output 
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```