# How can I subtract the values in two lists with the same lengths in python without using built-in function (only using loops)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to subtract the values in two lists with the same length to form a new list. For example if I had list1=[3,3,3] and list2=[2,2,2] I want to write a program that subtracts the components and gives list3=[1,1,1]

I have tried this:

```
def calcMeanDiff(numbers1,numbers2):
    for n in range(0,len(numbers1),1):
        difference=[abs(numbers1[n]-numbers2[n])]
```

This is giving me a float and not a list

Comment: You can use `zip` like `[abs(x-y) for x,y in zip([1,2],[3,4])]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subtract values in one list from corresponding values in another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677860/subtract-values-in-one-list-from-corresponding-values-in-another-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

```
def calcMeanDiff(numbers1,numbers2):
    diff = []
    for i in range(len(numbers1)):
        difference=[abs(numbers1[i]-numbers2[i])]
        diff += difference
    return diff
```

You should create a new list to hold the difference.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `zip` built-in to do what you want in the following way (yes, I know you said only using `for`):

```
def calcMeanDiff(numbers1,numbers2):
    return [abs(x-y) for x,y in zip(numbers1,numbers2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def calcMeanDiff(numbers1,numbers2):
    difference=[]
    for n in range(len(numbers1)):
        difference.extend([abs(numbers1[n]-numbers2[n])])
    return difference

list1=[3,3,3]
list2=[2,2,2]

list3=calcMeanDiff(list1,list2)

print(list3)

# output [1,1,1]
```

you need to add the calculate difference value to a list and then return that 
list. you have done is in each loop you assign those values to the difference(variable)
which change for each loop.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you'll have to initialize a list then find the differences and append that to the end (this only works if the lists are the same length):

```
def calcMeanDiff(numbers1,numbers2):
    diff = []
    for i,j in zip(numbers1, numbers2):
        diff.append(abs(i-j))
    return diff
```