# How to subtract each element of an array from another array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two Numpy arrays A (n x 1) and B (m x 1) of different sizes. I want to subtract each element of B from all the elements of A. Thus the elements of the result matrix C (m x n) should be computed as `c(i,j) = A(i)-B(j)`. Is there any direct loop-less computation using Numpy?

Comment: have you looked at `numpy.subtract`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subtract values in one list from corresponding values in another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677860/subtract-values-in-one-list-from-corresponding-values-in-another-list)

Comment: Why can't it be a loop?

Comment: @JakeP Numpy.subtract does not help. Please note that arrays are not of the same size, and I want to subtract A from every single element of B.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Broadcasting:

```
A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
B = np.array([5,4,2,7])
A - B[:, np.newaxis]
```

Output:

```
array([[-4, -3, -2, -1,  0],
       [-3, -2, -1,  0,  1],
       [-1,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [-6, -5, -4, -3, -2]])
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use **[np.meshgrid](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html#numpy-meshgrid)**

```
A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
B = np.array([5,4,2,7])
a, b= np.meshgrid(A,B)
print(a - b)

#output:- 
array([[-4, -3, -2, -1,  0],
       [-3, -2, -1,  0,  1],
       [-1,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [-6, -5, -4, -3, -2]])
```

Second method:-

```
C = A - np.array([B]).T
print(C)

#output:- 
array([[-4, -3, -2, -1,  0],
       [-3, -2, -1,  0,  1],
       [-1,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [-6, -5, -4, -3, -2]])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can be a little more efficient than a straightforward loop if you use list comprehension:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40])
b = np.array([1, 2])


c = np.array([a - b[j] for j in range(len(b))])
print(c)
```

output:

```
[[ 9 19 29 39]
 [ 8 18 28 38]]
```

Comment: that's loop's use; not what OP wants.

Comment: it's still a loop